# Why doesn't ASP.NET MVC 3 enable client-side validation in this case?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-javascript, unobtrusive-validation

I'm trying to integrate unobtrusive client-side validation in my ASP.NET MVC 3 project, as per [Brad Wilson's recipe](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html). However, it does not get enabled in the rendered view. For example, my `<input>` elements (i.e., editor fields) do not receive a `data-val` attribute as prescribed.

I have done the following to enable unobtrusive client-side validation:

`Web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

`Options.cs`:

```
public class Options
{
    // Annotate with validation rules, in order to generate client-side validation code 
    [Required, StringLength(60)]
    public string Bugs = "";
}
```

`_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<head>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

`Options.cshtml`:

```
@model MyProject.Models.Options

<div id="options-form">
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Options</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Bugs)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Bugs)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Bugs)
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

This HTML gets generated for the editor field:

```
<div class="editor-label">
  <label for="Bugs">Bugs</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
  <input class="text-box single-line" id="Bugs" name="Bugs" type="text" value="" />
```

As you can see, no `data-val` attribute :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to use `form`. Surround your fieldset with `Html.BeginForm`

```
<div id="options-form">
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Options</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Bugs)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Bugs)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Bugs)
    </div>
  </fieldset>
}
</div>
```

This will initialize `FormContext` and your inputs will receive data-val-* validation attributes

Comment: Appears I have to specifically use Html.BeginForm(), just entering a <form> tag myself has no effect. Thanks!

Comment: If you use manual form tag, you have to initialize FormContext manually too. @{
    ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();
}